# Controle transacional no contexto de tratamento de exceções usando Demoiselle

Tags: demoiselle

Olá,

estou com dúvidas sobre o controle transacional via Demoiselle (@Transactional) no contexto de tratamento de exceções com o ExceptionHandlerInterceptor do Demoiselle.

Eu tenho o seguinte web service:

```
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.transaction.Transactional;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.exception.ExceptionHandler;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.stereotype.Controller;

@WebService
@Controller
public class SislvServiceImpl implements SislvService {

    @Override
    @WebMethod
    @Transactional
    public RegistrarLaudoRetorno registrarLaudo(SolicitanteHeader solicitanteHeader, RegistroLaudoRequest laudoRequest)
            throws MalformedMessage, InternalServerError, Unauthorized, LaudoRejeitado {

        OperacaoRegistrarLaudo op = Beans.getReference(OperacaoRegistrarLaudo.class);
        return op.registrarLaudo(solicitanteHeader, laudoRequest);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    public void excecao(Exception e) throws Exception {
        SislvExceptionHandler handler = Beans.getReference(SislvExceptionHandler.class);
        handler.handle(e);
    }

}
```

Ao executar `op.registrarLaudo()`, em algum momento o seguinte método será executado para que a chamada ao WS seja adequadamente auditada:

```
private void auditarNoBancoSislv() {
    AuditoriaRequisicaoWs auditoriaRequisicaoWs = auditoriaRequisicaoWsFactory.createAuditoriaRequisicaoWs();
    auditoriaRequisicaoWsDAO.insert(auditoriaRequisicaoWs);
}
```

Nesse caso, o caminho feliz, tudo ocorre corretamente!

Mas se o método `op.registrarLaudo()` dispara alguma exceção, então teremos o tratamento feito pelo exception handler em SislvServiceImpl e a execução do método `handler.handle()`. Em algum momento o método 'handler.handle()' também executará o método de auditoria `auditarNoBancoSislv()`. O problema é que como tivemos uma exceção que interrompeu a execução de `sislvServiceImpl.registrarLaudo()`, a transação aberta em `sislvServiceImpl.registrarLaudo()` não será efetivada, e assim o método `auditarNoBancoSislv()` não surtirá efeito: a auditoria não será gravada no banco de dados!

Minha tentativa de solução foi a seguinte, alterar o método `excecao()`  para

```
    @ExceptionHandler
    @Transactional
    public void excecao(Exception e) throws Exception {
        SislvExceptionHandler handler = Beans.getReference(SislvExceptionHandler.class);
        handler.handle(e);
    }
```

A ideia é que se uma exceção ocorrer em `sislvServiceImpl.registrarLaudo()`, o Demoiselle irá ordenar o rollback dessa transação (TransactionalInterceptor) e também irá executar meu método `sislvServiceImpl.excecao()` (ExceptionHandlerInterceptor). Aí quando o método `sislvServiceImpl.excecao()` for executado, uma nova transação seria aberta para podermos gravar coisas no banco, já que a transação anterior já teria sido fechada. Mas não funcionou! =(

Outra tentativa foi a seguinte:

```
@Transactional
private void auditarNoBancoSislv() {
    AuditoriaRequisicaoWs auditoriaRequisicaoWs = auditoriaRequisicaoWsFactory.createAuditoriaRequisicaoWs();
    auditoriaRequisicaoWsDAO.insert(auditoriaRequisicaoWs);
}
```

Nesse caso a lógica seria: para o caminho excepcional, ao se chegar nesse em `auditarNoBancoSislv()` não há nenhuma transação ativa, então abre-se uma nova transação, o que não funcionou!!! Já para o caminho feliz, o Demoiselle teria que perceber que já existe uma transação ativa, e simplesmente não fazer nada para que o código aproveitasse a transação já ativa, o que funcionou, embora não sei se exatamente como o descrito.

Em ambas as tentativas, anotei com o @Controller do Demoiselle as classes contendo os método anotados com o @Transactional. E em ambos os casos os objetos contendo os métodos anotados com o @Transactional são instanciados via CDI.

E por último, mas não menos importante, meu `beans.xml`:

```
<beans ...>
    <interceptors>
        <class>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.exception.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor</class>
        <class>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.transaction.TransactionalInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

Obs: o comportamento de rollback quando acontecer uma exceção é o que eu quero para a aplicação. Só no momento da auditoria é que eu quero efetivar a gravação no banco em qualquer circunstância.

Por fim, a ajuda que preciso é para encontrar uma forma de persistir os dados em banco ao invocar o DAO no caminho excepcional, que começou a ser executado por um método invocado pelo ExceptionHandlerInterceptor do Demoiselle logo após uma exceção ter interrompido um método anotado com o @Transactional do Demoiselle.

Grato pela atenção!

Leonardo Leite

=================

Edição posterior: nova tentativa.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

public class Auditor {

    @Inject
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory; 

    ...

    private void auditarNoBancoSislv() {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        AuditoriaRequisicaoWsDAO auditoriaRequisicaoWsDAO = new AuditoriaRequisicaoWsDAO(entityManager);
        AuditoriaRequisicaoWs auditoriaRequisicaoWs = auditoriaRequisicaoWsFactory.createAuditoriaRequisicaoWs();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        auditoriaRequisicaoWsDAO.insert(auditoriaRequisicaoWs);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

Não deu certo. Erro:

```
16:22:15,319 ERROR [br.gov.serpro.siscsvws.SiscsvExceptionHandler] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1) Erro interno inesperado.: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.getTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1019) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1.jar:4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1]
    at br.gov.serpro.siscsvws.auditoria.Auditor.auditarNoBancoSislv(Auditor.java:48) [classes:]
```

Linha 48 é a `entityManager.getTransaction().begin();`.

Informação adicional, `persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence ...>

    <persistence-unit name="siscsv-ds" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/SiscsvDS</jta-data-source>

        <class>br.gov.serpro.siscsv.entity.auditoria.AuditoriaRequisicaoWs</class>
        ....

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="siscsv" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Obs: versão do Demoiselle: 2.5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em resumo, o jeito que resolvi foi deixando de usar a anotação @Transactional e fazendo o controle transacional por meio da interface UserTransaction.

Em termos de código, o resultado ficou algo equivalente a:

```
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.exception.ExceptionHandler;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.stereotype.Controller;

@WebService
@Controller
public class SislvServiceImpl implements SislvService {

    @Inject
    private MyTransactor transactor;

    @Override
    @WebMethod
    public RegistrarLaudoRetorno registrarLaudo(SolicitanteHeader solicitanteHeader, RegistroLaudoRequest laudoRequest)
            throws MalformedMessage, InternalServerError, Unauthorized, LaudoRejeitado {

        transactor.begin();
        OperacaoRegistrarLaudo op = Beans.getReference(OperacaoRegistrarLaudo.class);
        RegistrarLaudoRetorno retorno = op.registrarLaudo(solicitanteHeader, laudoRequest);
        transactor.commit();
        return retorno;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    public void excecao(Exception e) throws Exception {
        transactor.rollback();
        transactor.begin();
        SislvExceptionHandler handler = Beans.getReference(SislvExceptionHandler.class);
        Exception e = handler.handle(e);
        transactor.commit();
        throw e;
    }

}


========================================


import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

public class MyTransactor {

    @Inject
    private UserTransaction userTransaction;

    public void begin() {
        try {
            userTransaction.begin();
        } catch (NotSupportedException | SystemException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Não consegui iniciar transação", e);
        }
    }

    public void commit() {
        try {
            userTransaction.commit();
        } catch (SecurityException | IllegalStateException | RollbackException | HeuristicMixedException
                | HeuristicRollbackException | SystemException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Não consegui finalizar transação", e);
        }
    }

    public void rollback() {
        try {
            userTransaction.rollback();
        } catch (IllegalStateException | SecurityException | SystemException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Não consegui cancelar transação", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Eu cheguei a fazer tentativas com a anotação @TransactionAttribute, mas não obtive sucesso. Por isso mantive a opção pelo controle "manual" da transação. Mas está funcionando.

Answer (score 1):

O problema ocorre porque uma vez que o método `registrarLaudo` está anotado com `@Transactional`, todos os métodos invocados a partir dele serão aninhados na mesma transação. Logo, um *rollback* em qualquer momento da operação vai impedir o *commit* de todas as transações aninhadas.

Para resolver essa situação é preciso criar uma outra transação (independente) para os logs de auditoria.

O recurso [ManagedExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html) do Java EE 7 traz o que parece ser uma excelente alternativa para essa necessidade. [Aqui](https://martinsdeveloperworld.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/using-java-ees-managedexecutorservice-to-asynchronously-execute-transactions/) tem um exemplo de como esse recurso pode ser utilizado.